# How to merge entities in mariadb using the cursor

Tags: mariadb, database-cursor

Giving the following dataset:

| start_dt | stop_dt | grp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2010-02-14 | 2010-10-20 | 1 |
| 2010-10-21 | 2010-11-11 | 1 |
| 2013-01-01 | 2013-04-04 | 2 |
| 2013-02-02 | 2011-05-05 | 2 |

I want to merge those dates that belong to the same group and based on: if the stop_dt + 1 day = start_dt of another element, or if the start_dt in between start_dt and stop_dt of another element.

The desired result:

| start_dt | stop_dt |
| --- | --- |
| 2010-02-14 | 2010-11-11 |
| 2011-01-01 | 2011-05-05 |

I was able to achieve this by processing the whole dataset, however, I want to process element by element using cursor. With my current approach I am able to merge them, however I end up with other unwanted records (because I am doing double insertion, and no deletion)

```
create procedure test_curser() 
begin
    DECLARE done BOOLEAN DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE p_id BIGINT UNSIGNED;
    declare c1 cursor for
    select id from initial_table;
    DECLARE CONTINUE handler FOR SQLSTATE '02000'
    SET done = 1;
    open c1;
    fetch c1 into p_id;
        while not done do call sort(p_id);
            fetch c1 into p_id;
        end while;
    close c1;

create procedure sort(in p_id int)
begin
    insert into result(id, start_dt, stop_dt, grp) 
    (select id,start_dt, stop_dt, grp from initial_table where id = p_id);  
    
    # We check: If the table contain only one element then no merging is require, otherwise merge
    if (select count(id) from result) > 1 then
        insert into result(start_dt, stop_dt,grp) 
        (select if(r2.start_dt < r1.start_dt, r2.start_dt, r2.start_dt) as start_dt,
                if(r2.stop_dt > r1.stop_dt, r2.stop_dt, r1.stop_dt) as stop_dt,
                r1.grp
                from result as r1 join result as r2 
            on r2.grp = r1.grp and
            datediff(r2.stop_dt, r1.start_dt) = -1 or 
            (r1.start_dt between r2.start_dt and r2.stop_dt)
             where r1.id = p_id);
    else
        select 'process...';
    end if;
end
```

Check the [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/x2HsFboJ)

I am using `10.4.12-MariaDB`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Cursors are very cumbersome and add up complexity at solving this task. A more streamlined way of solving this task would consist in:

- generating islands for each of your consecutive (stop_dt, start_dt) values (difference of one day), using a `CASE` + a running sum
- applying an aggregation on your "*grp*" field and your newly created partition by identified islands, with `MIN` and `MAX` aggregate functions

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, CASE WHEN ADDDATE(LAG(stop_dt) OVER(PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY id), 1) = start_dt 
                   THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS changed_value
    FROM initial_table
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, SUM(changed_value) OVER(PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY id) AS islands_partition
    FROM cte
)
SELECT MIN(start_dt) AS start_dt, 
       MAX(stop_dt)  AS stop_dt
FROM cte2
GROUP BY grp, islands_partition;
```

You can then create your "*result*" table using:

```
CREATE TABLE result_table AS 
WITH cte AS ...
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/ArIaukpD).

**Optional Note**: for a better understanding, I'd suggest to check the output of every step of this query:

1. `SELECT * FROM cte`
2. `SELECT * FROM cte2`

Comment: Thanks for the response. As I mentioned, I was able to solve this problem using **similar** approach as yours. I am aware that cursor add more complexity/slower, however, I need to solve this problem with it.

Comment: Hope this answer will help someone working on a similar problem in the future.